# More precedence- Shebang line or perl command?

Tags: perl, scripting, shebang

I have multiple Perl scripts where the shebang line is outdated. Thats is, shebang points to an older version of Perl.

Old per path:

```
#!/data/oracle10.0/perl/bin/perl
```

The new version of Perl is in

```
#!/data/**oracle11.0**/perl/bin/perl
```

I have softlinked the perl command to the location of new version of perl.

```
perl -> /data/oracle11.0/perl/bin/perl
```

Now, the shebang points to older version and perl command points to newer version.

So, when I do `perl sample.pl`, the shebang gets ignored.

I wrote some sample scripts to see that. It seems the shebang line is ignored when I used the `perl` command. But I remember this was not the case with older version of perl (Shebang was considered over `perl` command).

So my question is, did the new version of perl(5.10) and older version (5.8) have different behaviour with respect to the shebang line? Does the new  version of Perl ignore shebang line if perl command is passed to it?

Comment: Run `which perl` from cmd line to check what are you actually using. `chmod 755 script.pl; ./script.pl` to force perl from shebang.

Comment: Perl has always scanned the shebang line for additional command line arguments, but it does not `exec` the other Perl.  The intended consumer of the shebang line is your shell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you run `perl myscript.pl` this starts the `perl` binary and gives it `myscript.pl` as input, which it then runs.  In this case, you will *always* get the first `perl` binary from your `$PATH`, regardless of Perl version.  As mpapec said in his comment, you can determine which `perl` this is by using the command `which perl`.

When you run `./myscript.pl` your shell looks for a shebang line and, if one is present, it executes the program listed in the shebang and gives it the file contents as input.  (If not, the shell itself attempts to process the file's contents.)  In this case, you will *always* get the `perl` at the path from the shebang, again regardless of Perl version.

This is basic *nix behavior and has not changed between Perl versions (because it's not managed by `perl` in the first place).

Comment: I believe that with `./myscript.pl` it is the kernel that looks at the first 16 bits (in a process forked by the shell) and if it's `#!` it tries to run (`execl`?) that, and if that fails the shell gets a shot.